# Debugging laserJet 200 software installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer, hp-laserjet

On Windows 7 X64, I am trying to install the latest version of the software package for the *HP LaserJet 200 color MFP M276*: `LJ-Pro-200-color-MFP-M276-full-solution-14057.exe`

Most interested I am in the scanning software, but I chose to install all default components, i.e. I didn't change the selection. Following recommendations in the HP support forum, prior to installation I did:

- Deinstall possibly conflicting HP software (*Programs and Features*) and printers (*Devices and Printers*) from failed previous attempts.
- In `msconfig.exe`, disable all non-Microsoft service and all startup items.
- Re-register `Atl.dll`: `regsvr32 Atl.dll`
- Re-register Microsoft Windows Installer: `msiexec /unregister`,
  `msiexec /regserver`
- Reboot.

I also tried running the installation package as Administrator.

Still when trying to run the installer, I either get error 1603 or a simple message without further details: *“A problem occurred while preparing to install software to your system. Please restart your computer, and run this installer again. If the problem persists, please check the product support web site for your product.”*

[image: Screenshot of install dialog with error message]

*What else can I try? Is there a log? How do I find out what is going wrong?*

In case you feel bored, and you want to give it a try: You don't need the LaserJet 200. The software package explicitly needs to be installed with the device disconnected.

Comment: [In this HP document it show how to scan with the Basic HP driver](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02455020)

Comment: [Similar issue solved here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software-Drivers/A-solution-to-1603-Fatal-install-error-at-driver-preloading/td-p/1353399)